# Prepend a single key-value pair to an Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
if (!array_key_exists('ip', $value)) {
    array_unshift($value, ['ip' => ""]);
}
```

.. this appends a new array, but I just need a key-value pair, like so:

```
Array
(
    [ip] => 192.168.1.1
    [firstname] => John
    [lastname] => Appleseed
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$value = array ('foo' => 'bar');
if (! array_key_exists('baz', $value)) {
    $value = array ('baz' => 'quux') + $value;
}
var_dump($value);
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/LbJhl).

Answer (score 0):

[Use array_merge:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$value = array_merge( array('ip' => "..."), $value );
```